# Raspberry pi python spi.open error (FileNotFoundError)

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, spi

I want to use Raspberry pi to programming a chip in python language. However, the spi.open(1,0) function doesn't work. Here is the first few lines of my code:

```
import spidev
from time import sleep
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(1,0)
```

the error appears when I run the code above

[image]

I am sure the spidev package has been installed while the spi interface has been enabled. I have tried to use other bus/device such as spi.open(0,0) but the same error shows again. I have also tried to modify the config file and it doesn't work as the file can't be changed... Could anyone please help me on this problem? many thanks.

Comment: The picture about the error can be displayed by clicking the blue link

Comment: see  https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=154317 and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/73095/filenotfounderror-with-spi-function

Answer (score 3):

Is your SPI enabled via sudo raspi-config?
I think that is what you are missing. Enable it and reboot your pi, it should get fixed.

Comment: Same problem. Thank you!

Comment: I am having the same problem but I am on ubuntu which doesn't have a raspi-config. What are my options?